# finding min, max, and average with different character type

Tags: java, max, min

I was success to find min,  max and average in my code . The code like this :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tugas {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 

    int    count       = 0;     
    double countTotal = 0;

    //... Buat Perulangannya
    System.out.print("Enter values (separate by space) : ");

    while (input.hasNextDouble() ) { 
        //... Get the next value.
        double value = input.nextDouble();

        //... Compare this value to max and min. Replace if needed.
        if (value > max) {
            max = (int) value;
        }
        if (value < min) {
            min = (int) value;
        }

        //... Keep track of these values for average calculation.
        count++;                 // Count the number of data points.
        countTotal += value;   // Keep a running total.
    }

    //... Be sure user entered at least one data point.
    if (count > 0) {                                          //Note 2
        //... Display statistics
        double rata = countTotal / count;

        System.out.println("Min = "  + min);
        System.out.println("Max = "  + max);
        System.out.println("Average = "  + rata);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No Data...!");
    }
}
```

}

oke, if I am inputting : 
Enter values : 1 2 3 4 5 ,
the output is : min 1, max= 5, average = 3.0

the problem is, my code is not automatically counting when I am pressed "enter".

And how to when I am input : a b 8 9 7 c d
it will be looping untill get the correct input

so :
Enter values :  a b 8 9 7 c d
it print "Please input the digit type"
Enter values :6 2 4 6 7 2 3 5 3
min : 2
max : 7
average : 4.2222

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slight modification that accepts an entire line from the Scanner, then parses it.  It validates the line upon parsing, per your specifications, looping if input is invalid.

Are you sure that you want min and max to be cast to type int?  The rest of the app seems to deal in doubles.

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Tugas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        int count = 0;
        double countTotal = 0;

        //... Buat Perulangannya
        boolean validinput = false;
        String valueSetLine = null;
        while (!validinput) {
            System.out.print("Enter values (separate by space) : ");
            valueSetLine = input.nextLine();
            if (valueSetLine.matches("^(-|-?\\d*\\.?\\d+(\\s-?\\d*\\.?\\d*)*)$"))  {
                System.out.println("valid string");
                validinput = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("invalid input");
            }
        }
        String[] doubleStrs = valueSetLine.split("\\s");
        double[] values = new double[doubleStrs.length];
        int i = 0;
        for (String s : doubleStrs) {
            try {
                double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
                values[i] = d;
                i++;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                nfe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        for (double value : values) {
            //... Compare this value to max and min. Replace if needed.
            if (value > max) {
                max = (int) value;
            }
            if (value < min) {
                min = (int) value;
            }

            //... Keep track of these values for average calculation.
            count++;                 // Count the number of data points.
            countTotal += value;   // Keep a running total.
        }

        //... Be sure user entered at least one data point.
        if (count > 0) {                                          //Note 2
            //... Display statistics
            double rata = countTotal / count;

            System.out.println("Min = " + min);
            System.out.println("Max = " + max);
            System.out.println("Average = " + rata);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Data...!");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: so thanks you so much. Your method to solve this problem so awesome. But, how to get the correct output when I am input : a b 8 9 7 c d.  the output  will be looping untill get the correct input

so, the ouput like this  : Enter values : a b 8 9 7 c d ,it print "Please input the digit type" Enter values :6 2 4 6 7 2 3 5 3 min : 2 max : 7 average : 4.2222 and "Congratulation". Thanks...Mer

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, all that is needed is to change the lines 
`
                System.out.println("valid string");
                validinput = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("invalid input");
            }
`
to 
`
                
                validinput = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please input the digit type.");
            }
`
It is already set up to loop until input is correct.  The only difference would be in the printout.

Comment: Oke, thanks. SO helping me in my newbie of java. Once again, thanks mer